# Why did the Google Drive extension on my Mac suddenly do this?

Tags: google-drive

So I'm sitting here using my Mac normally, not doing anything Google Drive and suddenly these two dialog boxes popup on the screen:

[image]

What I want to know is:

1. Why now, when I was literally nowhere near Google Drive or any of the folders on my computer that it uses?
2. Was there a problem before? Why did this just pop up now?
3. What does it mean? The Google Drive extension has worked fine before. It seems to be syncing okay too. What has changed?

Answer (score 1):

Mojave happened, with its new strategy... 'no perms, no run'.

Expect this to get more strict with 10.14.5 & the new 'notarisation' checks.

> With the public release of macOS 10.14.5, we require that all developers creating a Developer ID certificate for the first time notarize their apps, and that all new and updated kernel extensions be notarized as well.

See [App Notarization: A Quick Primer](https://blog.fleetsmith.com/macos-mojave-app-notarization/) & the many onward links at the bottom.